# terminal converts first letter to uppercase

Tags: centos, zsh, virtualbox

After a `$ vagrant ssh` into a Centos 7 VM, -
If I type a command in the VM terminal that uses zsh shell, the first letter gets uppercased.

How can I stop this behaviour? I briefly looked at `$ stty -lcase`, but that command did not work.

Comment: What happens if you backspace over the uppercase letter and retype the lowercase letter? What happens if you precede the letter with Ctrl-V? What happens if you run a command like `cat` and type text into its input?

Comment: if I backspace or use ctrl+v, I can proceed with lowercase. cat uppercases.

Comment: youre getting escapes at the head of the line *(or losing them, rather)*. i think i remember some stty setting for no returns on the first character of the line... you should definitely be playing with onlret, onlcr inlcr and etc. You might look at istrip - but i think the terminal is returning back over half of an input character - control chars are all upper case. It might be nulls eating half of the character too - that would probably relate to the newline n[123] setting.

Comment: ok, I will try some more stty settings

Answer (score 2):

the right command was `$ stty iuclc` after I checked the settings with `$ stty -a`

the real problem maker was the program Textexpander.
I figured that out when I had the issue in my regular terminal shell and the option `iuclc` was not available.